# How to stop SVN from "restoring" a checked out directory

Tags: svn

I have structure like

```
/root
    /branches
    /tags
    /trunk
```

I checked out root and got all three directories.  I really didn't want this.  I only wanted the /root, /branches and /trunk.  I don't want the /tags on my local machine, it is too big.  If I delete it locally, SVN tries to "restore" it whenever I update the /root.

I could delete the whole thing and start over, but I have a bandwidth limit and these are very big.  I already have the /branches and /trunk up-to-date, I just want to remove and stop the update of /tags (to recover space and avoid accidentally starting an update/restore on it).

How do you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called a ["sparse directory/checkout"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html). Do it like this:

1. Check out the project root with no contents into the current directory

   ```
   svn co [REPO-URL] --depth emtpy .
   ```
2. Update the working copy to include all of `trunk`...

   ```
   svn up trunk --depth infinity
   ```
3. ...and `branches`:

   ```
   svn up branches --depth infinity
   ```

Now, doing an `svn update` in the current directory will update the `trunk` and `branches` directories, but not care about the `tags` directory - it will effectively be ignored.

---

**Update:** Regarding the question how to alter an existing working copy - this is possible as well:

```
svn up tags --set-depth empty
```

This will remove all of the `tags` folder's contents (but not the folder itself) from the working copy.

Comment: This is good for future work.  But I have already checked out trunk and branches and would like to not have to download all that data again.  Is there a way to make SVN "forget" about /tags and not "recover" the /tags directory after I delete it?  Or is there a way to setup a sparse directory, then make it use the folders I've already checked out?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are updating /root. This contains /root/branches. (And will even if you start over.)

If you run svn command against /root/trunk and /root/branches, you won't have this problem.